# how magento 2 generats and archives log files in file system in server?

Tags: magento2, configuration, cron, log

I have been searching in internet for this question "how Magento 2 generate log files and make archive files when the day passes is there an cron or configuration in admin area so I can change it for example archive log files monthly ?

thank you in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento doesn't rotate logs like you seem to be implying. However, you've likely seen logs get rotated on some servers in locations like `/var/log/` where those are rotated by the OS itself. On many Linux servers you'll find a folder called `/etc/logrotate.d/` that contains definitions of what files/logs you'd like to rotate. Here's an example one I use to rotate logs for Magento.

File: `/etc/logrotate.d/magento`

```
/path/to/magento/var/log/*.log {
    su www-data www-data
    create 640 www-data www-data
    daily
    compress
    missingok
    notifempty
    rotate 50
}
```

This runs logrotate each night, compressing and renaming log files to only keep single day increments of the logs up to 50 days. The username `www-data` should be substituted for whichever user your webserver is running as.

Some more info on using logrotate:

- [Man Page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)
- [Digital Ocean Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-logfiles-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Thanks @Rhys  I was confused :)